# Can I get rid of Alt F2 run command from Dash?

Tags: unity-dash

Is there a way to have the Alt F2 run command prompt not open from the dash?  Instead, it it's own window like in fallback Gnome?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead enter Alt-Ctrl-T and open a full terminal window where you can enter one command, or many, and see the output of each.

Comment: I'm more looking for something like this: http://cdn.shuffleos.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/command_prompt.jpg

Comment: Would you please update your question with this qualification?